# Creating a structure using an aggregation query that groups by 2 ids

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have a collection of various documents similar to what is shown below as 3 objects.

```
{
comment:{ 
      text_sentiment: "positive",
      topic: "A"
   }
}, // DOC-1

{
comment:{ 
      text_sentiment: "negative",
      topic: "A"
}}, // DOC-2

{
comment:{ 
      text_sentiment: "positive",
      topic: "B"
}},..//DOC-3 ..
```

I want to write an aggregation that returns results in the following structure:

```
{
   topic: "A",
   topicOccurance: 2,
   sentiment: {
      positive: 3,
      negative: 2,
      neutral: 0
   }

},...
```

I have written an aggregation that is able to group for `topic` and `text_sentiment` but I do not know, how can I create a structure similar to the one shown above. Here is the aggregation that I created.

```
   db.MyCollection.aggregate({
       $match: {
           _id: "xyz",
           "comment.topic": {$exists: 1},
       }
   },{
       $group: {
           _id: {
               topic: "$comment.topic",
               text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
               
           },
           total: {$sum: 1},
           
       }
   },{
       $project: {
           topic: {
               name: "$_id.topic",
               occurence: "$total"
           },
           sentiment: "$_id.text_sentiment"
       }
   },{
       $sort: {"topic.occurence": -1}
   })
```

It grouped by `topic` and `sentiment`,  but the structure does not match the one above. How can I get a similar structure?

Comment: Hi, does the `text_sentiment` (positive, negative, neutral) is fixed text?

Comment: @YongShun Yes, it is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1**

You need 2 `$group` stages.

1. `$match`
2. `$group` - Group by `comment.topic` and `comment.topic` and `$sum`.
3. `$group` - Group by `_id.topic`, `$sum`; and add `text_sentiment` and `total` from previous stage into `text_sentiments` via `$push`.
4. `$project` - Decorate output documents. Set `sentiment` with converting from `text_sentiments` array to key-value pair via `$arrayToObject`.
5. `$sort`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "xyz",
      "comment.topic": {
        $exists: 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        topic: "$comment.topic",
        text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.topic",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      text_sentiments: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
          v: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      topic: "$_id",
      topicOccurance: "$total",
      sentiment: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$text_sentiments"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "topicOccurance": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Answer 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tkz7_BhXgbW)

---

**Answer 2**

As mentioned `text_sentiment` values are fixed, you can use the query below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "xyz",
      "comment.topic": {
        $exists: 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$comment.topic",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      text_sentiments: {
        $push: "$comment.text_sentiment"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      topic: "$_id",
      topicOccurance: "$total",
      sentiment: {
        "positive": {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$text_sentiments",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $sum: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this",
                        "positive"
                      ]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "negative": {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$text_sentiments",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $sum: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this",
                        "negative"
                      ]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "neutral": {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$text_sentiments",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: {
              $sum: [
                "$$value",
                {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this",
                        "neutral"
                      ]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "topicOccurance": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Disadvantage: When the `text_sentiment` value is added/removed, then you have to modify the query.

[Sample Mongo Playground (Answer 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uWXb4lALKKc)

---

**Answer 3**

Another approach similar to Answer 2 is using `$size` and `$filter` to replace `$reduce`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      //_id: "xyz",
      "comment.topic": {
        $exists: 1
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$comment.topic",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      text_sentiments: {
        $push: "$comment.text_sentiment"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      topic: "$_id",
      topicOccurance: "$total",
      sentiment: {
        "positive": {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$text_sentiments",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this",
                  "positive"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "negative": {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$text_sentiments",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this",
                  "negative"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "neutral": {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$text_sentiments",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this",
                  "neutral"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "topicOccurance": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Answer 3)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mat6ObbafoG)

Comment: A small correction (for answer - 1). The second stage will compute total as `total: {$sum: "$total"}` (Not checked other answers yet)